# PHP Email sending BCC

Tags: php, email, bcc

I know there are a few similar questions to this but I just can't get it working.

Ok, I have a list of emails grabbed from my database in a variable called $emailList. 
I can get my code to send an email from a form if I put the variable in the `$to` section but
I cannot get it to work with bcc. I've even added an email to the `$to` incase it was that but it doesn't make a difference.

Here is my code.

```
$to = "name@mydomain.com";
$subject .= "".$emailSubject."";
$headers .= 'Bcc: $emailList';
$headers = "From: no-reply@thepartyfinder.co.uk\r\n" . "X-Mailer: php";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= 'THE MESSAGE FROM THE FORM';

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    $sent = "Your email was sent!";
} else {
    $sent = ("Error sending email.");
}
```

I've tried both codes:

```
$headers .= 'Bcc: $emailList';
```

and

```
$headers .= 'Bcc: '.$emailList.';
```

It's not that the emails aren't separated because they are. I know they are because it works if I put `$emailList` in the `$to` section.

---

I Should add, ignore the `$message` bits and the HTML stuff. I've not provided all of that so that is why it's missing from this code.

Comment: You are missing the "\r\n" after your BCC header and then you are overwriting the headers on the next line with From.

Comment: I've tried with \r\n as well. So where do I put the bcc? Does it need to be in a specific place?

Comment: @drew010, your comment should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @drew010 Thanks a lot! It's working now. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @BenToms no worries I was lazy, glad you got it working now.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You have `$headers .= '...';` followed by `$headers = '...';`; the second line is overwriting the first.

Just put the `$headers .= "Bcc: $emailList\r\n";` say after the `Content-type` line and it should be fine.

On a side note, the `To` is generally required; mail servers might mark your message as spam otherwise.

```
$headers  = "From: no-reply@thepartyfinder.co.uk\r\n" .
  "X-Mailer: php\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: $emailList\r\n";
```

Comment: I've never had an issue when not specifying 'To' in the headers.

Comment: I don't doubt it. I just mean there are a variety of mail servers and spam filters out there and emails with missing/strange header bits generally get higher spam scores.

Answer (score 13):

You were setting BCC but then overwriting the variable with the FROM

```
$to = "name@mydomain.com";
     $subject .= "".$emailSubject."";
 $headers .= "Bcc: ".$emailList."\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: no-reply@thepartyfinder.co.uk\r\n" .
     "X-Mailer: php";
     $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
 $message = '<html><body>';
 $message .= 'THE MESSAGE FROM THE FORM';

     if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
     $sent = "Your email was sent!";
     } else {
      $sent = ("Error sending email.");
     }
```

Comment: The `\r\n` should be in double quotes otherwise it is taken literally.  Only the one on the `BCC` had this problem.