# send multiple emails with single destinatary

Tags: php, email

i want to send email to multiple destinataries but in destinatary shows only the email and not the others mails

for example :

instead of:

`mail('juanito@gmail.com,jua@gmail.com,juana@gmail.com', $asunto, $html,$header);`

in mail box: http://prntscr.com/6g4zkz

could be in mail box: http://prntscr.com/6g4zz1

but sending the 3 emails ?

**Edit:**

i solved like this:

```
while ($resulta = $dati->fetch_array()) {
            $email = $resulta['email'];
            mail($email, $asunto, $html,$header);
        }
```

the only problem is i dont know how to return true or false:

```
public function feed_mail($id){
        $mysqli = $this->connection();
        $data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM feed");
        $dati = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM feed");
        $dato = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM blog where id='$id'");
        $resultado = $dato->fetch_array();
        $title = $resultado['title'];
        $date = $resultado['date'];
        $autor= $resultado['author'];
        $body = base64_decode($resultado['body']);
        $asunto = 'Ortoflex - '.$title;
        while ($resultados = $data->fetch_array()) {
        $html = '<div style="width:80%;padding: 100px; background: #E4EDF6;border:10px solid #000000;">';
                        $html .= '<h1><b>'.$title.'</b></h1>';
                        $html .= '<br>';
                        $html .= $date;
                        $html .= '<hr>';
                        $html .= '<br>';
                        $html .= $body;
                        $html .= '<hr><br>';
                        //while ($resultados = $data->fetch_array()) {
                        $html .= '<a href="'.$this->url.'unsuscribe?hash='.$resultados['hash'].'">Anular Suscripci&oacute;n</a>';   
                        }
                        $header .="MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
        $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n"; 
        $header .="From: Ortoflex.mx<feed@ortoflex.mx>\n";
        $header .="Return-path: feed@ortoflex.mx\n";
        $header .="X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion()."\n";
        //$header .= "Bcc: ".$item."\r\n";
        $to = 'private-feed@ortoflex.mx';       
while ($resulta = $dati->fetch_array()) {
            $email = $resulta['email'];
            mail($email, $asunto, $html,$header);
        }

            return true;

    }
```

Comment: You can put them all in cc, or instead save email addresses in an array, and iterate through it to send emails one by one

Comment: how i can iterate them?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525415/php-email-sending-bcc

Comment: the mails are stored in the db so i call them with a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User BCC in the header

```
$to=array(); 
$headers .= 'From: Jack.com <admin@website.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $to) . "\r\n"; 
if(mail(null, $title, $content, $headers))
  return true; 
else 
  return false;
```

or

convert the string to array and iterate over it

```
$ids='juanito@gmail.com,jua@gmail.com,juana@gmail.com'
$emails[]=explode(" ", $ids);
$errors[]="";
for($i=0;$i<count($emails);$i++)
{
  if(!mail($emails[$i], $asunto, $html,$header)){
      $errors[]="Email function didn't work for".$emails[$i];
   }

}
```

Another way if you want to know the exact error (by using try and catch)

```
for($i=0;$i<count($emails);$i++)
{
  try{
     mail($emails[$i], $asunto, $html,$header);
     }
    catch(Exception $exception){
     $errors[]=$exception->getMessage(). " <- exception for email   ".$emails[$i];
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks how i add to the fuction? to return true or false if where errors?

Comment: i mean this: if(mail($to, $asunto, $html,$header)){
   return true;
 
  }else{
   return false;
   
  }

Comment: if(!mail($emails[$i], $asunto, $html,$header)){       $errors[]=false;
   }
else{ $errors[]=true;}

Comment: $errors is an error and it has all the error statuses with respect to emails.

Comment: you can use
$to=array();
$headers .= 'From: Jack.com <admin@website.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $to) . "\r\n";
if(mail(null, $title, $content, $headers)) return true; else return false;

Comment: what if it sends first few emails and fails on the others?

Comment: you can use $to=array(); $headers .= 'From: Jack.com <admin@website.com' . "\r\n"; $headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $to) . "\r\n"; if(mail(null, $title, $content, $headers)) return true; else return false;

Answer (score 1):

send the mail by placing ur destinataries in BCC. That what your recipient wouldn't be able to see others email address. Following is the sample code

Set you email field to null and

```
$to=array();
$headers .= 'From: Jack.com <admin@website.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $to) . "\r\n";


mail(null, $title, $content, $headers);
```

Comment: i need to be in destinatary and bot in bcc

Answer (score 0):

Use This :-

```
$headers .= 'From: SmsGratisan.com <admin@website.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $to) . "\r\n";


mail(null, $title, $content, $headers)
```