# Sendmail sending to multiple addresses but in seperate emails

Tags: php, sendmail

I'm trying to send multiple separate emails to multiple addresses. The below code sends it in 1 email with multiple TO addresses. This becomes an issue because everyone in the email can see each other's email addresses.

Is there a way to send separate emails?

```
<?php

$smtp       = 'xxx.com';
$port       = 25;
$secure     = 'tls';

$username   = 'test@xxx.com';
$pass       = '';
$from       = 'test@xxx.com';
$to         = 'info@xxx.com';
$to1        = '';
$subject    = 'Test Email';
$content    = $mail_content;

require_once("include/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail=new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
try{
    $mail->Host         = $smtp;
    $mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
    $mail->Port         = $port;
    $mail->SMTPSecure   = $secure;
    $mail->Username     = $username;
    $mail->Password     = $pass;
    $mail->SetFrom($from);

    if (isset($email) && $email) {
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
    }
    else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            $mail->AddAddress($row->email);
            echo $row->email."<br>";
        }
    }

    $mail->Subject      = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($content);
    $mail->Send();

    if (isset($email) && $email) {
?>
        <script>location.href="<?php echo '../index.php' . $_REQUEST['redirect']; ?>";</script>

<?php
    }
}
catch (phpmailerException $e){
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: You can loop through all of your email addresses and send a mail for each iteration of the loop instead of adding an address only for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Could you please share how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Send the email in the BCC.

Look here for an example :

[PHP Email sending BCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525415/php-email-sending-bcc)

Comment: Thanks used this before but it didn't look professional as the email looks like spam.

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop that checks for all of the email addresses and then assigns the email address to `$mail->AddAddress()`.

All you need to do in this same loop is send the email with `$mail->Send();` with each iteration of the loop as well

```
//PHPmailer object
$mail=new PHPMailer(true);

//set up
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host         = $smtp;
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
$mail->Port         = $port;
$mail->SMTPSecure   = $secure;
$mail->Username     = $username;
$mail->Password     = $pass;
$mail->SetFrom($from);
$mail->Subject      = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($content);

//add address
if (isset($email) && $email) {
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
}
else {
    //loop through the DB results 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {

        //you already have this
        $mail->AddAddress($row->email);
        echo $row->email."<br>";

        //now send it here as well
        $mail->Send();

        //Do more stuff here
    }
}
```

I have not tested this on my local system but this is one way to send the mail individually for each address as an alternative to sending one mail and using `bcc`.